# Django conditional for rendering template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to django and am trying to only render text which does not have the word 'After' or 'Before' in it. However this didnt break anything but it didnt actually remove those values?

I looked at using a regex but this really isnt recommended for django templates.

```
{% if "After" not in window.name or "Before" not in window.name %}
    {{window.event_id}}-{{window.name}}
{% endif %}
```

The codebase I am working on makes it almost impossible to remove these values in the models before you get to the template... I can only apologise for maintaining and putting up with this!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you mean when you say: "However this didnt break anything but it didnt actually remove those values?"

Comment: @DanielHolmes yes sorry. My aim is to filter out all strings (window.name) which contain After or Before in them. So that only window.name is rendered when it does not contain those two words. But I believe the current statement is always true so it just does nothing currently.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your condition is always true.

Here's one way to do it. Probably not the most ideal.

```
{% if "After" in window.name or "Before" in window.name %}

{% else %}
{{window.event_id}}-{{window.name}}
{% endif %}
```

This way it only prints if neither 'Before' or 'After' is in the string. I didn't test this code but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. I was going to try this but I wasn't sure it was syntactically correct for Django. I agree it probably isnt great but honestly this codebase I am on this fits right in!